# Can not load image into index.js in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

Problem:

My image would not show up when I render the code. It only returns the icon for when an image is not loaded correctly. I have read that I need to add my image to the public folder so the webpack will not affect the path, but I do not know how to add it correctly to the public folder. Is is a special path to this  public folder, or do I need to do any specific stuff to make a folder public?

I have tried the following:

- Add image to a folder called "public" and importet the file inside index.js like this:

  ```
  import img from '../../public/myimage.jpg';

  <img src={img} />
  ```
- and also tried to just add the path directly inside src:

  ```
  <img src="../../public/myimage.jpg" />
  ```
- and I have also tried the same thing with the image inside the same folder as the index.js file with this path:

  ```
  './myimage.jpg"
  ```

but these efforts have not worked. How can I add an image to my React code?

Comment: If you are using Create React App, and you have put the image in the `public` directory, you can render it with `<img src="/myimage.jpg" />`.

Comment: I am unfortunately not using that boilerplate, but thank you for the idéa!

Comment: The `public` directory is specific for CRA, that's why it isn't working for you if you are using something else. What environment are you developing in? A custom Webpack project?

Comment: Aha, I see.. Yes, it is custom. But I know that I should make the image file public somehow, but I do not know how.

Comment: Alright. Then `import img from '../../public/myimage.jpg';` should work for you, granted that the path is correct. Do you get a Webpack error?

Comment: I have tried this, but I get an webpack error. The error is: Sending WebSeal error for url: a-path-to-image.png

Comment: try to install babel-loader and do as you did <img src={img} />

Comment: @ReidunMarie That does not sound like a webpack error actually. Does the error occur at transpile time (when building the bundle) or at runtime (when actually using the app)?

Comment: Please also add your webpack config to the question. Likely your loader is not correctly configurated. You definitely need to `import` the image rather then just passing the path as a prop. By importing it you will tell weback that you need the image to be copied to the bundle destination. But you have to make sure that your server is capable of serving it from there and the loader has to be correctly configurated to generate the correct public url to the image.

Comment: @trixn When I run the app with "npm run start" I get the error, and when I open the app I see an icon that indicates that the image was not loaded correctly

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `public` folder append process.env.PUBLIC_URL before the image filename.

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder) (regarding Webpack):

> If you put a file into the public folder, it will not be processed by
>   Webpack. Instead it will be copied into the build folder untouched. To
>   reference assets in the public folder, you need to use a special
>   variable called PUBLIC_URL.

Example:

```
return <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/myimage.jpg'} />;
```

Comment: This is only required if you do not `import` the image. It is generally encouraged to explicitly import assets and let webpack figure out the correct public path. Doing it outside of the module system is only recommended for [some edge cases](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder#when-to-use-the-public-folder).

Comment: @trixn OP has stated in the question that he/she has tried what you have suggested already to no avail

Comment: Then he/she did something wrong obviously because that is how it should be done and I don't see why you should provide a way that is explicitly called an "escape hatch" in the docs (at least it should be stated as that in the answer) instead of helping to find the solution to do it correctly. The error he/she talked about in the comments does more likely point to an incorrect public path being generated or the webserver not being correctly configured to serve the image from its location.

Comment: @trixn If you wish to add an answer, then please do so.

Comment: I wish to do so that is why I asked OP for more information because at the moment it is not clear enough. I just wanted to point out that this answer proposes a solution that is surely made for edge cases.